# ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here I have mentioned the Files I have used. I have tried in both ways, by adding and removing of "type" : "module"  tag in package.json file.

**App.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('app.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);

import { hello } from './sell.js';
hello();
```

**app.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React JS </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Tutorial</h1>

<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**sell.js**

```
export let hello = () => {
    console.log("heyy shreya suman");
}
```

Comment: why are you using both ESM syntax and commonjs? change `import {hello} from './sell.js'` to `const {hello} = require('./sell.js')`

Comment: It seems you are missing that the javascript running on the server and the javascript running in each browser page are two totally separate programs. You cannot mix them - you need to make them communicate.

Answer (score 8):

Look, there are 2 ways to import somthing

1. `var http = require('http');`
2. `import http from "http"`

But you cant use `import` and `require()` at the same time, it does not work. You either use `require()` or `import` And, your package.json module type or file extension must match the type of import you are using